# SpriteKit UILabelNode Attach Event

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am using SpriteKit framework for my game. I am displaying a menu and now I need to find out if the SKLabelNode is clicked or not. How can I do that?

```
 SKLabelNode *startGameLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Marker Felt"];
    startGameLabel.text = @"Start";
    startGameLabel.position = CGPointMake(0, -40);

    [gameOverScreenBackground addChild:startGameLabel];
```

Comment: A couple of ways. Either subclass it and enable user interaction and override touchesBegan, or implement touches began in the class in which you're adding the label, and check to see if the node at the touch location is the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do it...

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene
{
     SKLabelNode *startGameLabel;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
         startGameLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
        startGameLabel.fontSize = 40.0;
        startGameLabel.text = @"Start";
        startGameLabel.name = @"start";
        startGameLabel.position = CGPointMake(200,200);
        [self addChild:startGameLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(startGameLabel.frame, touchLocation))
    {
        NSLog(@"stop touching me!");
    }
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    //
}

@end
```

Comment: In my case my SKLabelNode is contained inside a SKSpriteNode (Menu). How can I handle if play again label was clicked in this scenario.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. You can check for any number of node frames being touched. Instead of the NSLog statement, you can divert to another method by using something like [self playAgain]; Then set up the method playAgain to reset the game to the start.